# При подключении устройства в Android Studio определяется версия SDK 1

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

В Android Studio создается проект с minSDKver=19 (Android 4.4.2), после чего запускается проект с отладкой на устройстве с этой же версией Android, но отладчик ругается, что у устройства minSDKver=1, хотя, если проект скомпилировать и установить самостоятельно на устройство - проект работает без нареканий. В чем может быть проблема?

ОС - Debian Jessy, Android Studio - 1.4.1

Comment: Да, есть временами такой глюк. Мне обычно перевтыкание USB-шнурка в устройство помогает. А разбираться из за чего такое желания нет.